# Getting all connected network devices

Tags: c#, networking

I am working on a C# application and I am trying to get a list of all of the devices that are connected on my local network.

However, when I run the app, I don't get all of the network devices, for example, my PC running the program and retrieving the network devices doesn't find my phone even though my phone and my PC are both on the same WiFi network.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
IPGlobalProperties network = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = network.GetActiveTcpConnections();

            foreach (TcpConnectionInformation connection in connections)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Device IP: {0}", connection.RemoteEndPoint);
                if (connection.RemoteEndPoint.Address.Equals("192.168.1.66"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                }
            }
```

Comment: you will have to do something like nmap to find it. `IPGlobalProperties` is only for your local computer and its current state.

Comment: ...and even nmap isn't necessarily always going to be 100% correct, although it's a great resource. You can also look into doing an ARP ping on all hosts on your network.

Comment: Devices on a network can be configured to be nearly invisible, and there are things like Private VLANs where you cannot communicate with any other devices on the same network. There is no guaranteed way to discover every device on your own network because the protocols were not designed that way.